# Insert data into a column only if it has NULL value, else update it

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update data into a column in a table only if the data sent from the HTML page is not NULL or ''. Else, that column must not be touched. Example :-

**table_1**

```
id      name         age        rent        
==========================================
1       Name 1         25         1000         
2       Name 2         28         NULL          
3       Name 3         35         1500          
4       Name 4         44         3200          
5       name 5          42        NULL
```

LET THE DATA SENT FROM HTML PAGE IS STOERED IN A VARIABLE `today_rent` AND THIS VARIABLE IS SENT TO MYSQL.

**MySQL Query**

```
IF(today_rent !=null OR today_rent != '') THEN
UPDATE table_1 SET rent=today_rent WHERE id=2
END IF;
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You don't insert into columns, `INSERT` creates new rows.

Comment: You're missing the table name in the `INSERT` query.

Comment: If that code (with the typo fixed) does what you want, I don't think there's a better way to do it. You can't combine those `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries into a single query.

Comment: `NULL=NULL` is `NULL` which is not true. You probably mean `IF (rent IS NULL)`.

Comment: Provide desired final table data state.

Comment: @tadman That could be it. I need to try it out. And also , I think my messed up my question. I wanted to update that column only when **the user had some data sent from the HTML page**. Otherwise, it would not update that column. The problem is sometimes, even if there is no data, the column is updated as a blank space

Answer (score 1):

Add an index

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx ON test (id, (CASE WHEN rent IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE id END));
```

Then use

```sql
INSERT INTO test (id, rent) 
VALUES (@id,@new_rent) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rent = VALUES(rent);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c48a44a6268e2e1710162b337efa592b

PS. The query does not set `name` and `age` columns - but their setting necessity is not described in the question.